# Why button onclick fires multiple times?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, event-handling, dom-events

I have a *ajaxmodalpop* and it has some controls like the below; The problem is whenever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on textbox it sets focus to the button (that is correct) but **If I press five or 6 times (or many times) <kbd>Enter</kbd> key very quickly then the button fires as many times as I pressed enter key.**
Although I have a validation function on client click of the button and it must not (even can't go through from validation function if textbox values are cleared) pass that function for every second time, because I clear the textbox value from server side.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPurpose" runat="server" TabIndex="4" Width="558px" Style="text-transform: uppercase; overflow: hidden" CssClass="textleftWithBorder" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeydown="ConvertEnterToTab(event)">/asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmitNAdd" TabIndex="5" Text="Submit & Add" ClientIDMode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="true" onkeydown="HandleLeftRightArrow(event,'btnClose','btnSubmitAndClose')"                  OnClick="btnSubmitNAdd_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate()" />
```

and functions are:

```
    function ConvertEnterToTab(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.htmlEvent.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            var nextElement = document.getElementById("btnSubmitNAdd");
            if (nextElement != undefined) {
                nextElement.focus();
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                e.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

  function Validate() {
        if (ValueOf("txtCustomerName") != _CustomerResetText) {               
                return true;
            }
            else {                    
                return false;
            }           
    }

  function HandleLeftRightArrow(event, leftControl, rightControl) {
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (code == 39) {
            if (document.getElementById(leftControl).disabled == false)
                SetControlFocus(rightControl);
        }
        else if (code == 37) {
            if (document.getElementById(rightControl).disabled == false)
                SetControlFocus(leftControl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you don't want the event to fire twice (or more) per second, add a flag with a timeout. Is it that what you want?

Comment: It should fire as many times as some one hit "Enter" key but it should go through the validate function because there I have code to check whether it can go to the server side or not? But so far Whenever it is going to the serversicde event as many times as I press. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable the button if it passes the validation when it is clicked.

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="if(Validate()){this.disabled=true;}"
```

Comment: I tried this disabling technique before but the problem with this is that the button's server side event is not fired due to the diabled = true.

Comment: No. I 'll try and let you know in a minute!

Comment: It has the same problem even for submitbehaviour="false".

Comment: It is not firing the click event if I set submitbehaviour =false.

Comment: Make sure its `UseSubmitBehavior` and not `submitbehaviour`

Comment: Yes it is UseSubmitBehavior="false". Now Button's server side event is not firing.

Comment: ok for all intents and purposes, can you try removing the `Validate()` test and see if the server side event will fire if `UserSubmitBehavior="false"`. Something like `UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"`

Comment: Thank you @Andy Refuerzo for your quick assistance. It worked when I triggered the button's server side event in onclientclick using the _doPostback("",'').